# GoogleMap.addGroundOverlay() takes a lot of UiThread time

Tags: android, google-maps, android-anr-dialog

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<GroundOverlayOptions> goArray;
```

- ca. 2-3k of elements.
When i try to display it like this:

```
for (GroundOverlayOptions temp : goArray) {
   map.addGroundOverlay(temp);
}
```

it takes a lot of UiThread time (ca. 10-15s) and it creates ANR bugs.
**map.addGroudOverlay() must be run on UiThread.**
Is there any workaround for this?

content of goArray:

```
float longitude, float latitude, float width,float height, int color
{
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap
            .createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixel(0, 0, color);
    final BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromBitmap(bitmap);
    final LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(latitude
            - height / 2, longitude - width / 2), new LatLng(latitude
            + height / 2, longitude + width / 2));
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    GroundOverlayOptions go = new GroundOverlayOptions().image(image)
            .positionFromBounds(bounds).transparency(0.33f);
    goArray.add(go);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try *AsyncTask* to do that?

```
private class MapTask extends AsyncTask<GroundOverlayOptions, Integer, Void> {
    protected Void onPreExecute() {
        //Use something like ProgressBar to keep user informed
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(GroundOverlayOptions... maps) {
        //Will need to use maps[0] 
        //because that method treat this param as an Array
        for (GroundOverlayOptions temp : maps[0]) {
            map.addGroundOverlay(temp);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //Update ProgressBar
    }
 }
```

The place where you doing the loop call *AsyncTask* to handle this.
Pass the *goArray* to *AsyncTask*.

```
new MapTask().execute(goArray);
```

Comment: not working - `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
            at com.google.l.a.ce.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ct.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ft.a(Unknown Source)`

Comment: One thing that I was reading is about _TileOverlay_ and _GroundOverlay_, it look likes _TileOverlay_ is more appropriated to do that.
Have you considered to use _TileOverlay_ instead of _GroundOverlay_? I can see that you are using a loop statement to assign some values to goArray and after that loading one after another. Probably you have more than one loop, consider to use another thread to process all of then. Maybe that was the starting point of your delay. Could you please post the full code (related to the problem) and the full stacktrace.